How to write to the dev system within a Flutter widget test?
During a widget test, I want to write to the dev environment file system, instead of writing to the device's file system. (So, using dart.io instead of path_provider.)
For reason's I don't understand, the writeAsString function hangs. E.g., here's a minimal example where execution hangs on the writeAsString call and never reaches the debugPrint line. The TestFile.txt is created within the package root directory, but it is empty. I'm running on a Mac.
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Try writing to dev system within test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(const SizedBox.shrink());
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    final file = File('TestFile.txt');
    await file.writeAsString('Some Text');
    debugPrint('Test completed');
  });
}


Try wrapping with runAsync

Or just use writeStringSync.
